# Facebook Graph API how to post a comment to another user's public post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

It works posting on pages stories with:

```
postId + "/comments"
```

where postId is for example

```
postId = "360637130688291_377801902305147"
```

but when posting into a user's public story that allows comments like [this one](http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?id=1430496489&story_fbid=4047336948376) the graph api is not able to find it.

`"1430496489_4047336948376/comments"` gets a reply as :

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Error finding the requested story","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

Is this a common issue or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a valid id: https://graph.facebook.com/1430496489_4047336948376

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested it in the [http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=POST&path=1430496489_4047336948376/comments) with all permissions on, and it seems this is impossible.

Probably to avoid spam, otherwise anyone could start creating applications that would run through posts on other users walls, and leave a comment there with a link to the nearest porn site.

Strangely this works for posts on third party owned pages.